# Is it possible to make the wireless debugging port static?

Tags: android, adb, adbwireless

I have a Google Pixel 7 phone using Android 13, not rooted.

Is there a way to specify a static port when doing wireless debugging, so that it doesn't change if you turn off and then turn on Wireless debugging? If it changes after reboot that's fine, I don't reboot my phone that often.

I saw people saying to install nmap and write a shell script to search for the port, I don't want to do any of that, entering and connecting to the port is easy for me via a VScode extension.

I want to make the Android wireless debugging port static, if possible.

Comment: Not possible without root.

Comment: @m0skit0 ok cool then, not a problem. Please post an answer so I can accept it and close this question.